# Is there any ORMs support Posgresql JSONB DocumentDB in Nodejs like MartenDB in .NET

Tags: node.js, postgresql, .net-core, orm, prisma

I'm having 2 microservices that use the same database.

The first (.NET Core) use MartenDB to manipulate the data, so my data schema generated by Prisma was like:

```
model mt_doc_users {
    id               String    @id(map: "pkey_mt_doc_users_id") @db.VarChar
    data             Json
    mt_last_modified DateTime? @default(dbgenerated("transaction_timestamp()")) @db.Timestamptz(6)
    mt_version       String    @default(dbgenerated("(md5(((random())::text || (clock_timestamp())::text)))::uuid")) @db.Uuid
    mt_dotnet_type   String?   @db.VarChar
    mt_deleted       Boolean?  @default(false)
    mt_deleted_at    DateTime? @db.Timestamptz(6)
  
    @@index([mt_deleted], map: "mt_doc_users_idx_mt_deleted")
}
```

The **data** column is actually the model class in my program.

Then I want to extract the schema of the data column into Prisma schema, is there any ORM based on Nodejs that supports that?

Comment: What did you end up doing to accomplish that?